# Serialization of parent model including child models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have models - Commodity, Clother and child models, as Acessories, Outwear, etc.:

```py
class Commodity(models.Model):
    atribute = models.CharField()

class Clother(models.Model):
    commodity = models.ForeignKey(Commodity)
    clother_atribute = models.CharField()

class Acessories(models.Model):
    clother = models.ForeignKey(Clother)
    acessories_atribute = models.CharField() 

class Outwear(models.Model):
    clother = models.ForeignKey(Clother)
    outwear_atribute = models.CharField()
```

How can I serialize the parent model Commodity to call all vertical dependencies? I suppose to query Commodity id and get all Clother attributes and Acessories or Outwear attributes.

Comment: Do you use the Django serializers?

Comment: I use Django REST Framework  model serializers.

Comment: Well since there is no concept in Django like "vertical dependencies", you probably have to list those yourself. Yes, you can walk through the model-relation graph, but detecting cycles make things complicated.

Comment: Thanks, well noted. Hoped to meet something like this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I understood your problem you can define `ClotherSerializer`. You can use [`depth = 1`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) to serialize nested objects in this serializer:

```
class ClotherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Clother
        fields = ('id', 'acessories_set', 'outwear_set')
        depth = 1
```

Later in your `CommoditySerializer` you can use `ClotherSerializer` to serialize clother and all it's relation:

```
class CommoditySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    clother_set = ClotherSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Commodity
        fields = ('id', 'clother_set')
```

Comment: Can you actually passe a list of children in the parent's object, to create a parent and multiple children at the same time? Have tried but for some reason it seems that the parent object doesn't accept a list of children objects, although their relationship has been clearly defined in their models. Any hint on how to manage this?

Comment: @Seb try to check writable nested serializer part in the docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So have tried but am still getting an error "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list." in the parent's object field corresponding to its children. Any hint on why it behaves that way when I have a many to one relationship between the children and the parent?

Comment: You my friend saved me so much time. For whatever reason I could not figure out this simple `depth = 1` fix. Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, this can also be achieved using `SerializerMethodField`: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

```
class ClotherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for Clother data model.
    """
    acessories = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    outwears = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Clother
        fields = ('id', 'acessories', 'outwears')

    def get_acessories(self, clother):
        return AcessoriesSerializer(clother.acessories_set.all(), many=True).data

    def get_outwears(self, clother):
        return OutwearSerializer(clother.outwear_set.all(), many=True).data


class CommoditySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for Commodity data model.
    """
    clother = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Commodity
        fields = ('id', 'clother')

    def get_clother(self, commodity):
        return ClotherSerializer(commodity.clother_set.all(), many=True).data
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**`drf-writable-nested`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested) package for that and specify in a serializer *how* to serialize certain fields. By using another *serializer*, you thus specify that it it serialized by calling the serializer for these children:

```
class CommoditySerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    clother_set = ClotherSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Commodity
        fields = ("atribute", 'clother_set')


class ClotherSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Clother
        fields = ("clother_atribute",)
```

Of course you can add more such relations, for example to specify `Acessories` for a `Clother`.

I advice you look at the GitHub page, and use this as a template for your own serializer.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this functionality natively without any extra methods, you need only get the Clother dependency to the Commodity using it's [related name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). In this case, since the `related_name` reference is not defined, use the default related name like so:

```py
...
class ClotherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for Clother data model.
    """
    acessories_set = AccesoriesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    outwears_set = OutwearsSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Clother
        fields = ('id', 'acessories_set', 'outwears_set')


class CommoditySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for Commodity data model.
    """
    clother_set = ClotherSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Commodity
        fields = ('id', 'clother_set')
```