# DRF 2-way nested serialization with many to many relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-database

I have a *many-to-many* relationship between my *Student* and *Macro* models, using an intermediary model

```
class Person(models.Model):
    # cf/NIN optional by design
    cf = models.CharField(_('NIN'), unique=True, blank=True, null=True, max_length=16)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), blank=False, max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), blank=False, max_length=40)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(_('date of birth'), blank=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name']
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name


class Macro(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), unique=True, blank=False, max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Student(Person):
    enrollment_date = models.DateField(_('enrollment date'), blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True, null=True)
    macro = models.ManyToManyField(Macro, through='MacroAssignement')


class MacroAssignement(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='macros', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    macro = models.ForeignKey(Macro, related_name='students', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.student)
```

I configure serializers in order to exploit the nested serialization when I serialize students

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id',
                  'cf',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'date_of_birth')
        abstract = True


class StudentSerializer(PersonSerializer):
    macro = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta(PersonSerializer.Meta):
        model = Student
        fields = PersonSerializer.Meta.fields + ('enrollment_date',
                                                 'description',
                                                 'macro')
        extra_kwargs = {'enrollment_date': {'default': date.today()},
                        'description': {'required': False}}


class MacroSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    students = StudentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Macro
        fields = ('id',
                  'name',
                  'description',
                  'students')
```

Untill here no problem, when I request *student* data, the *macro* related information comes along with it. Here's an example

```
    {
        "id": 18,
        "cf": "ciaciacia",
        "first_name": "Paolo",
        "last_name": "Bianchi",
        "date_of_birth": "2020-05-01",
        "enrollment_date": null,
        "description": null,
        "macro": [
            "macro1"
        ]
    },
```

Now, on the contrary, when I request for a *macro*, I would like to view also the related *students* list. I've tried to implement nested serialization also in the **MacroSerializer**

```
class MacroSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        students = StudentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

This doesn't work, as I get the following error

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `first_name` on serializer `StudentSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `MacroAssignement` instance.
Original exception text was: 'MacroAssignement' object has no attribute 'first_name'.
```

[NOTE: `first_name` is a field of **Student** model inherited from **Person** model]

Of course I could implement a function to query the database and get the name of students assigned to a given macro, but I'm wondering if there's a buil-in django way of doing it. Kind of like *2-way nested serialization*

Comment: Hmm, you can try to add "related_name='students'" parameter in Student class macro field like this "macro = models.ManyToManyField(Macro, through='MacroAssignement', related_name='students')". Problem is that (i guess) Macro class does not have relation to Student class.

Comment: Also remember to prefetch_related students/macro for better performance :)

Comment: EDIT: Your "students" relation points now to MacroAssignement class. If you will add related_name='students' for macro field you will get an error because you will have two relations with the same name. I suggest to change name in MacroAssignement class from "students" to anything else and use "students" for macro field.

Comment: @monio Man, that worked! It's exactly what I meant. Thank you a lot. Also, good point about  **prefetch_related**, I'm gonna study it. I'll post my code as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in previous helpful comments, the fix is about using **related_name**. My code has been modified as following

**serializers.py**

```
class StudentSerializer(PersonSerializer):
    macro = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta(PersonSerializer.Meta):
        model = Student
        fields = PersonSerializer.Meta.fields + ('enrollment_date',
                                                 'description',
                                                 'macro')
        extra_kwargs = {'enrollment_date': {'default': date.today()},
                        'description': {'required': False}}

class MacroSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    students = StudentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Macro
        fields = ('id',
                  'name',
                  'description',
                  'students')
```

**models.py**

```
class Student(Person):
    enrollment_date = models.DateField(_('enrollment date'), blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True, null=True)
    macro = models.ManyToManyField(Macro, through='MacroAssignement', related_name='students')
```

Note that what I wrote in my question is actually a poor design decision, because it would lead to a circular dependency. Indeed, `StudentSerializer` would need `MacroSerializer` and viceversa. I highly suggest to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590895/circular-dependency-in-serializers) about dependencies in serializers

************ EDITED ************

Quick fix: set `depth = 1` in the related model serializer (in this case, *StudentSerializer*) Thanks to @neverwalkaloner answer [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968979/serialization-of-parent-model-including-child-models)